# ubuntu: write multiple lines to a text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cat, heredoc

I'm trying to write multiple lines to a text file like so:

```
cat <<EOT >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/eco.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eco.vagrant
    DocumentRoot /var/www/eco/website/public    

    <Directory var/www/eco/website/public/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>   

    # Logging
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/eco-error.log
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/eco-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
EOT
```

But I get `bash: /etc/apache2/sites-available/o-eco.conf: Permission denied`

So I tried `sudo cat...` but just the same.

I quite like having it like this, rather than a single line, as it's within a bash script and I can clearly see the content of what will be written with indentation etc.

What tool ought I use to write in this manner? Or how should I be using cat here?

Comment: You don't have permission to write to the file. The syntax doesn't matter.

Comment: This question would be better suited to Super User or the Linux SE site.

Answer (score 3):

If you do `sudo cat <<EOT >>filename`, the output redirection is happening in your original shell, not in the superuser process, so it still fails. You need to move the redirection into the superuser process, by executing a shell explicitly.

```
sudo bash -c 'cat <<EOT >>/etc/apache2/sites-available/eco.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eco.vagrant
    DocumentRoot /var/www/eco/website/public    

    <Directory var/www/eco/website/public/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>   

    # Logging
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/eco-error.log
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/eco-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
EOT
'
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to avoid having to deal with extra quoting is to feed the heredoc to `sudo tee` like:

```
sudo tee -a /path/to/file >&- <<EOT
...
EOT
```

- `tee filename` replaces `> filename`
- `tee -a filename` replaces `>> filename`
- Adding `>&-` (or `>/dev/null`) prevents a copy of everything `tee`  writes going to `stdout`.

Comment: The use of cat can be eliminated: `sudo tee -a /path/to/eco.conf >&- <<EOT`